# Computing md5 using Guava 14+ and Java 7

Tags: java-7, guava

I have a Java 7's [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html). I'd like to compute the md5 of the content of the file represented by that path.

I usually use Guava's hashing mechanism ([`ByteSource#hash(HashFunction)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteSource.html#hash%28com.google.common.hash.HashFunction%29)).

How do I go from a Java 7's `Path` to a guava's `ByteSource` so I can compute its md5? do I have to go through an intermediary `java.io.File`?

Yes, I know `ByteSource` and `Path` serve the same purpose. But some parts of my application use `ByteSource` and some other use `Path`.

P.S. I know I could use `java.security.DigestInputStream`. This question is an example of question about how to integrate Guava's `ByteSource`s with Java 7's `Path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you really have to go though `File`. Guava works for Java 6 (and even gets back ported to 5), so they can't refer to classes introduced in Java 7. Are there any problems with using `path.toFile()`?

Comment: This is what happens when I don't grep on the javadoc but perform a visual search on it: I missed that method, yet I use Path everyday. I never ever saw that transformation and was wondering if it would ever be possible, yet it simply exists. So to answer your question, maaartinus, no there are no problem using such a call. A more error prone approach would have, like taking the `String` representation of the `Path` and using it to create a `File`. Anyways, I think it'd be great that Guava uses `Path` natively (and therefore switches to Java 7).

Comment: @ogregoire: Nice... initially I was confused and had no idea what your problem could be. But now it's clear and missing something while scanning visually happens to me quite often.

Comment: Obviously this only works when working with the default file system (other `FileSystem` implementations have to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` from `toFile()`). We do have an internal class that provides implementations of `ByteSource` etc. for `Path`s, but as Guava targets JDK6 we can't expose it currently, as maaartinus mentions. (It should be pretty easy to write your own simple `Path`-based subclasses of `ByteSource` and `ByteSink` if you so desire, though.)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily write a `ByteSource` for a `Path` yourself.  Minimal example:

```
public class PathByteSource extends ByteSource {
    private final Path path;

    public PathByteSource(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream openStream() throws IOException {
        return java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(path);
    }
}
```

It may be prudent to override other methods like `size()` and `read()` for more efficiency.